# For Visual Clarity, How to change the syntax color of 'apostrophe' and "quotation mark" in vscode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

**Problem:** Python allows both and it would be easier for my eyes to see if the colors of apostrophe/quotation mark are different.

**What I've Tried**: I've changed the color of strings in settings.json. Of course, it didn't fulfilled my intention. Both apostrophe and quotation mark colors were changed.

```py
print('Name: "{}" Age: "{}"'.format(self.name, self.age)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it looks like Visual Studio Code (or rather TextMate - the [tokenization engine used by VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide#tokenization)) considers the scope to be the same for single and double quotes for Python, thus I do not think you can make them different colors.  You can inspect this using the "Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes" developer tool in Visual Studio Code:

[image: scope]

If you look at a different language, such as C#, it considers double and single quotes as different scopes:

[image: C# quotes]

This was tested using the following settings:

```json
    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "textMateRules": [{
            "scope": "string.quoted.single",
            "settings": {
                "foreground": "#33ff00" //the "bright green"
            }
        },
        {
            "scope": "string.quoted.double",
            "settings": {
                "foreground": "#0004ff" //the "darkish blue"
            }
        }
    ]}
```

I suppose they treated all quotes for Python as "single" since they mean the same, where as in other languages such as C#, they do not.